# How to tell Mathematica that my variable is a scalar

Tags: matrix, assumptions

In my calculations I have these combinations

```
PauliMatrix[1].f PauliMatrix[2]
```

where `f` is a scalar function.
The result is as if Mathematica assumes `f` to be a matrix:

```
{{0, -I {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}.f}, {I {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}.f, 0}}
```

I tried to attach a unit matrix to `f`:

```
PauliMatrix[1]  .f PauliMatrix[0] .PauliMatrix[2]
```

The result is the same.

Does anyone see a way to get the same output as from

```
In[131]:= f PauliMatrix[1]. PauliMatrix[2]

Out[131]= {{I f, 0}, {0, -I f}}
```

Comment: Put parantheses around `f PauliMatrix[2]'. It's interpreting the expression as dotting `PauliMatrix[1]` with `f` and then multiplying element-wise with `PauliMatrix[2]`, due to order-of-operations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Mathematica, the type of variable is interpreted based on the context, and if there are no values associated with the variable, then often nothing is done. When you write `PauliMatrix[1].f`, since there are no values/rules associated with `f`, this just returns

```
{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}.f
```

because the function `Dot` doesn't evaluate unless the arguments are vectors, matrices, or tensors (essentially, `List`s, I think).

When you then write

```
PauliMatrix[1].f PauliMatrix[2]
```

it interprets `{{0, 1}, {1, 0}}.f` as a single object and multiplies this object *as a scalar* by `{{0, -I}, {I, 0}}`, yielding

```
{{0, -I {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}.f}, {I {{0, 1}, {1, 0}}.f, 0}}
```

The problem is order of operations, essentially: your expression `Dot`s before it multiplies. Therefore, all you really need is a set of parantheses:

```
PauliMatrix[1].(f PauliMatrix[2])
```

which yields

```
{{I f, 0}, {0, -I f}}
```

Comment: For reference: [a precedence table](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/OperatorInputForms.html).