# Expanding a Matrix Vector product in powers of epsilon

Tags: series-expansion

I am attempting a perturbation expansion in Mathematica. As part of this, I would like to expand a matrix-vector product where the vectors are given in powers of epsilon. Eventually, I'd like to generate a `CoefficientList` in powers of epsilon of something like

```
$Assumptions=Q ∈ Vectors[3] && P ∈ Vectors[3] && A ∈ Matrices[{3, 3}];
A . (P ϵ + Q ϵ^2)
```

But first I would like to expand the second expression as

```
ϵ A.P + ϵ^2 A.Q
```

but mathematica doesn't seem to want to expand it. I thought that specifying $A$, $P$, and $Q$ as `Matrices` and `Vectors` but so far it hasn't been helpful.

I've looked at [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/266230/taylor-expand-around-a-vector) and [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/87020/how-to-tell-mathematica-that-my-variable-is-a-scalar), which come close to what I'm asking.

Eventually, I would like to be able to substitute in a particular matrix for $A$ but I think that while generating the sequence of equations at different orders in $\epsilon$ it makes more sense to leave it unspecified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`TensorExpand`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TensorExpand):

```
$Assumptions = Q ∈ Vectors[3] && P ∈ Vectors[3] && A ∈ Matrices[{3, 3}];
TensorExpand[A . (P ϵ + Q ϵ^2)]
```

> ϵ A . P + ϵ^2 A . Q

Comment: (+1) from me. Carl, do you know why `Distribute` does not work nicely even with an assumption on `ε`? The only reason I am asking is because `TensorExpand[A.(P + A)]` gives as output `A.P + MatrixPower[A, 2]` whilst `Distribute[A.(P + A)]` returns the more natural `A.A + A.P`.